# показать, скрыть меню при изменении состояния (<input type="checkbox">)

Tags: css

```css
  .menu { display: none; }  
  #navi:checked  ~ nav .menu { display: block; }
```

```html
  <div class="nav-trigger">
        <input type="checkbox" name="navi" id="navi">
        <label for="navi">Menu</label>           
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul class="menu">
       <li><a href="">home</a></li>
       <li><a href="">menu</a></li>
       <li><a href="">about</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

если (сhecbox,label)вынести за пределы DIV то все работает а как добраться до (.menu) в первом варианте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нормальными способами - никак. Css-селекторы не позволяют подняться наверх, так что надо вытаскивать input наружу, чтобы он был на одном уровне с изменяемым элементом или выше него. В обоих случаях он должен также идти до изменяемого элемента, поскольку возможности выбрать более ранний элемент в css тоже нет.

PS: Хотя допускаю, что каким-то жутким хаком удастся как-то извернуться (примерно [как тут](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/546946/178988)).